# In Python, can a loop be used within a function?

Tags: python, function, loops

I am just learning python and was trying to define a function using a `for` loop.
The code is as follows -

````
def chk(hilist):
``` The function returns the output of the enumerate function as (x1,y1) (x2,y2)...
```
    for item in enumerate(hilist):
        return item
````

I ran the above function for the input 'string' as below -

```
abc = chk('string')
abc
```

The output came out as (0,s).

If I ran the regular `for` function and the output will be as follows -
(0, 's')
(1, 't')
(2, 'r')
(3, 'i')
(4, 'n')
(5, 'g')

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up `yield` and `generator` in the Python documentation.

Comment: Your function `chk` exits and returns the first instance in the loop. Yes, loops can be used in functions but probably `yield` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return will break the function immediately.
So, you have to save the result in a list and return it:

```
def chk(hilist):
    """ The function returns the output of the enumerate function as (x1,y1) (x2,y2)...
    """
    ret_list=list()

    for item in enumerate(hilist):
        ret_list.append(item)
    return ret_list
```

Answer (score 1):

in Python (and in all programming languages), using the return keyword will get you out of the function, so I propose two solutions:

- solution 1: store your tuples in a list and then return the list
  itself
- solution 2: replace return with yield (but if you want to print returned items convert it to a list ex: `list(abc(some_arguments))`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to use `print(item)` if you wanna get all the enumerated values from 'string':

```
def chk(hilist):
    for item in enumerate(hilist):
         print(item)
```

This worked smoothly for me.